# Как правильно увеличить переменную?

Tags: javascript

Создаю игру на Phaser JS, не суть. Хочу сделать таблицу опыт=лвл.

250 опыта = +1 лвл
500 опыта = +1 лвл

Не знаю как правильно сделать. Если делаю через if или switch, то пока опыт равен 250 лвл добавляются без остановки. Как мне правильно добавить 1 лвл?

В итоге сделал так:

```js
if(xp >= 50 && lvl==1){
 lvl++;
} else if (xp >= 100 && lvl==2){
 lvl++;
}
```

Comment: А если в конструкции `if` проверять не только опыт, но и текущий уровень игрока? Например: `if(experience >= 250 && lvl < 1) lvl++;`

Comment: Идея и правда крутая. А дальше как? Там с 2,3...лвл?

Answer (score 1):

таблица это неправильный путь, если опыт повышается каждые 250, то можно текущий опыт делить на 250 и получать уровень, если рост не линеен то формулу конечно придётся немного уcложнить.
То есть сделать как то так

```
var xp = 2200;
var level = 0;
level = parseInt(xp / 250);
```

будет 8 Level. такой подход упростит задачу если уровней много

Comment: Это при условии, что требуемое кол-во опыта всегда одинаково. Но как показывает практика, в играх обычно требуемое кол-во опыта разное. Я уже молчу об играх с неограниченным уровнем. :)  
Но что ТС попросил, то мы ему и даём. Он же не спрашивал у нас, как лучше написать ему логику игры. :)

Comment: можно доработать формулу под любое адекватное изменение шага, например считать по экспоненте

Comment: Согласен. Но бывает и неадекватное изменение шага. Например в моём примере последние три значения: сначала +700 экспы, а потом +600. Вот тут уж никак без таблицы. Но я согласен, что в основном, чем код проще, тем лучше (если ситуация позволяет упрощать код). :)

Comment: тут больше вопрос проектирования, скажу честно, в росте уровней должна быть логика, я этого как игрок ожидаю, а как программист тут вопрос поддержки, представь таблицу на 100 уровней, а если надо больше ?поэтому мне кажется правильнее изначально выстроить какую-то логику. как я понимаю пока ещё можно что-то поправить, когда будет 100 мегабайт кода это станет уже почти нереально.

Comment: Согласен с вами и как игрок и как программист. :) Таблицу на 100 уровней боюсь представить. Уж лучше придумать закономерность, с увеличением требований с учётом текущего уровня. Насчёт 100 Мб кода - и тут вы правы. Я 2 года работал с написанным сторонними программистам движком игры (браузерка на PHP). Но недавно не выдержал и начал писать с нуля свой, ибо что-то менять в текущем или найти причину чужих багов - уж очень устал в чужом коде ковыряться.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать что-то такое (правильность работы не проверял, но должно работать):

```
// текущий уровень
var Level = 0;

// требования к уровню
var LevelRequirements = [250, 500, 1000, 1700, 2300]

// проверяем, стоит ли повышать уровень
function LevelUp()
{
    verify = false;
    while(verify == false)
        if(experience >= LevelRequirements[Level])
            Level++;
        else
            verify = true;
}
```

В самом начале устанавливаем уровень как нулевой. Создаём массив с требованиями по опыту. Первое значение в массиве - требование для первого лвл и т.д. На деле же, ключ первого значения - `'0'`, поэтому при проверке мы используем текущий уровень. Функцию проверки запускаешь в нужном тебе месте. В самой функции создаётся переменная для проверки, достигнут ли максимально возможный лвл. Пока он не достигнут - запускаем проверку на повышение уровня.

Этот пример создан с учётом фиксированного количества уровней. Если кол-во уровней не ограничено, то разумно было бы переделать этот пример с использованием шага на увеличение уровня, а не фиксированного кол-ва опыта.

P.S.: как упоминал Grundy в комментарии к другому ответу - функцию можно убрать вовсе, и запускать код из неё напрямую. Я же его вывел в функцию, так как не имею представление того, что ты делаешь и как именно работает твоя игра. :)

Answer (score -2):

```js
var lvlExpTable = {
  // lvl: min_exp
  'lvl1': 200,
  'lvl2': 400,
  'lvl3': 800,
  'lvl4': 1500,
  'lvl5': 2600,
  'lvl6': 4150,
  'lvl7': 7600,
  'lvl8': 13650,
  'lvl9': 20120,
  'lvl10': 28900

  // ... и так далее
};

function getMinExp() {
  return lvlExpTable['lvl' + lvl];
}

if (lvlExpTable.hasOwnProperty('lvl' + lvl)) {
  while (experience >= getMinExp()) {
    lvl++;
  }
}
```

Comment: не будет работать:`lvl` Это число, а ключи в объект `lvl1`, `lvl2` и т.д.

Comment: @Grundy уже исправил

Comment: а в чем смысл первого `if`? да и в данном случае функция как-то особо не нужна, тем более все переменные глобальные

Comment: слушай, ты senior-code-reviewer? :) ничего там критически лишнего нет

Comment: ну пока тут код ради кода, если убрать половину - ничего не изменится, а если еще и вместо объекта массив использовать - то еще и проще будет выглядеть

Comment: ну так бери и пиши код

Comment: Ну кто-то же должен следить, чтобы было поменьше плохих ответов :-)